# Presentation Error (PE) на 10 тесте python list задачки

Tags: python, test-automation

Пытаюсь решать задачку на python, 9 тестов на ОК но на 10м тесте выдает PE (Presentation Error). Какая может быть ошибка здесь?
У Саши и Даши есть карточки с цифрами. На каждой карточке написана ровно одна цифра. При этом у каждого из ребят может быть несколько карточек с одной и той же цифрой. Также может быть, что у кого-то нет ни одной карточки с какой-то цифрой.

Ребята хотят показать одно и то же число с помощью своих карточек (без ведущих нулей). Из всех чисел, которые они могут показать вместе, они хотят показать максимальное. Какое число покажут Саша и Даша?

Формат входных данных
В первой строке вводится набор цифр на карточках Саши без пробелов.

Во второй строке вводится набор цифр на карточках Даши без пробелов.

Гарантируется, что количество карточек у Саши и Даши по отдельности не превосходит 100000.

Формат выходных данных
Выведите максимальное число, которые могут показать Саша и Даша вместе с помощью своих карточек, без ведущих нулей. Если они не могут одновременно показать одно и то же число, то выведите −1.

входные данные
выходные данные
1)

280138
798081

8810

2)

123
456

-1

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
maxx = list(str(max(a, b)))
minn = list(str(min(a, b)))
lst = []
lst1 = []
for i in maxx:
    if i in minn:
        lst.append(i)
        minn.remove(i)

lst1= sorted(lst, key=int, reverse=True)

if lst1:
    print(*lst1, sep='',end="\n")
else:
    print(-1)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то задача из олимпиадного отделения мшп.Проблема кода в том что у тебя не учитываются ситуации когда будут ведущие нули.А в 10 тесте именно такой случай.Тоже щас бился с этим тестом после чего словил Run time на 26 тесте буду щас на ++ переписывать пытаться

Answer (score 0):

Недостатки:

- теряются лидирующие нули: попробуйте карточки `01` и `01`. Правильный ответ `10`, вы печатаете `1`;
- печатаются несколько лидирующих нулей: попробуйте `100` и `200`. Правильный ответ `0`, вы печатаете `00`;
- медленный (квадратичный) алгоритм.

Не нужно вводить строки с карточками как числа. Надо специально обработать печать нулей, если нет других цифр. Нужно ускорить обработку карточек если их много.

Считаем цифры (`collection.Counter`), печатаем их от больших к меньшим, специально обрабатываем нули:

```
import collections


a = collections.Counter(input())
b = collections.Counter(input())

found = False
for d in '9876543210':
    c = min(a[d], b[d])
    if c > 0:
        if d == '0' and not found:
            c = 1
        print(d * c, end='')
        found = True
if found:
    print()
else:
    print(-1)
```